# tinkercad arduino lcd is not displaying

Tags: arduino, display, lcd

How I wanted it to work:
This is a thing that checks temperature and display the temperature and the temperature that I want. You can change the hoping temperature by using the buttons. One is high and the other is low.If the temperature is higher the fan gets on.If the spaeaker rings just once when the temp is higher than what I wanted it to be.

There seems to be no error in the code but the lcd is displaying nothing.
The speaker, TMP, MOTOR seems to be working well which is strange.
Please help me what's wrong.

Code:

*

```
[//LCD_Thermostat
  #include <Wire.h>
  #define TEMP_ADDR 72
  #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
  LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
  byte degree\[8\] = {
   B00110,
   B01001,
   B01001,
   B00110,
   B00000,
   B00000,
   B00000,
   B00000,
 };
byte fan_on\[8\] = {
  B00100,
  B10101,
  B01110,
  B11111,
  B01110,
  B10101,
  B00100,
  B00000,
};
 byte fan_off\[8\] = {
  B00100,
  B00100,
  B00100,
  B11111,
  B00100,
  B00100,
  B00100,
  B00000,
};
const int SPEAKER=8;
const int DOWN_BUTTON =9;
const int UP_BUTTON=10;
const int FAN =11;
const int T0=0;
boolean lastDownTempButton    = LOW;
boolean currentDownTempButton = LOW;
boolean lastUpTempButton      = LOW;
boolean currentUpTempButton       = LOW;
int set_temp = 23;          
boolean one_time = false;   
void setup()
{
  pinMode(FAN, OUTPUT);

  //Create a wire object for the temp sensor
  Wire.begin();

  //Set up the LCD's number of columns and rows
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  //Make custom characters
  lcd.createChar(0, degree);
  lcd.createChar(1, fan_off);
  lcd.createChar(2, fan_on);

  //Print a static message to the LCD
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Current:");
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.write((byte)0);
  lcd.setCursor(11,0);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Set:");
  lcd.setCursor(10,1);
  lcd.write((byte)0);
  lcd.setCursor(11,1);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(15,1);
  lcd.write(1); 

}
boolean debounce(boolean last, int pin)
{
  boolean current = digitalRead(pin);
  if (last != current)
  {
    delay(5);
    current = digitalRead(pin);
  }
  return current;
}
void loop()
{/*
  Wire.beginTransmission(TEMP_ADDR); 
  Wire.write(0);                         
  Wire.endTransmission();              
  Wire.requestFrom(TEMP_ADDR, 1);   
  while(Wire.available() == 0);          
  int c = Wire.read();  
  */
  // for LM35 temperature sensor (Chapter3. 아날로그 신호와 센서값)
 int c = analogRead(T0);
 c = c*5.0 /1024.0 * 100;
 Serial.println(c);
 lcd.setCursor(8,0); //Move the cursor
 lcd.print(c); //Print this new value
  lcd.setCursor(8,0);                   
  lcd.print(c);                     

  currentDownTempButton = debounce(lastDownTempButton, DOWN_BUTTON);
  currentUpTempButton  = debounce(lastUpTempButton, UP_BUTTON);

  if (lastDownTempButton== LOW && currentDownTempButton == HIGH)
  {
    set_temp--;
  }
  //Turn up the set temp
  else if (lastUpTempButton== LOW && currentUpTempButton  == HIGH)
  {
    set_temp++;
  }
  //Print the set temp
  lcd.setCursor(8,1);
  lcd.print(set_temp);
  lastDownTempButton = currentDownTempButton;
  lastUpTempButton = currentUpTempButton;

  if (c >= set_temp)
  {
    if (!one_time)
    { 
      tone(SPEAKER, 400);
      delay(500);
      one_time = true;
    }
    else
    {
      noTone(SPEAKER);
    }
    digitalWrite(FAN, HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(15,1);
    lcd.write(2);
  }
  else
  {
    noTone(SPEAKER);
    one_time = false;
    digitalWrite(FAN, LOW);
    lcd.setCursor(15,1);
    lcd.write(1);
  }
}][1]
```

*

Comment: Maybe research over on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use LCD wiring as described in LiquidCristal library, use examples such as HelloWorld.

[Here you can find a 'Hello World' example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld)